# How to use await/async in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call a function in the **`ngOnInit()`** and feed it two values. So this is the function I'm trying to call inside the `ngOnInit`: 
`this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);`

The issue here is that `this.postIWant` and `this.theHardWords` are getting resolved in the `ngOnInit` itself as you can see below, which is causing the error. Now how can I call the **`this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);`** and feed it those values without getting an error?

I have been thinking about the await functions? But I can not figure it out, any advice on this, please?

This is my `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.wordsLoaded = false;
    this.postLoaded = false;
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      annotation: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(250)
        ]
      })
    });
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
    this.annotationService.getWords();
    this.annotationSub = this.annotationService
      .getWordUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((thewords: ComplexWord[]) => {
        this.thewords = thewords;
        this.thewords.map(word => {
          this.theHardWords.push(word.word);
          this.wordWithAnnotation.push(word);
        });
        this.wordsLoaded = true;
        this.isLoading = this.postLoaded && this.wordsLoaded;
      });
    this.postsService.getPosts();
    this.postsSub = this.postsService
      .getPostUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.posts.map(post => {
          if (post.id === this.id) {
            this.postIWant = post.fileText;
          }
        });
        this.postLoaded = true;
        this.isLoading = !(this.postLoaded && this.wordsLoaded);
      });
    this.role = this.authService.getUserRole();
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    this.authStatus = this.authService
      .getAuthStatus()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        this.role = this.authService.getUserRole();
      });
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great, as I am not too experienced in this field. Currently I am having to call `this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);` outside of the `ngOnInit` to avoid the error but obviously, I would like to call it automatically.

Comment: I think you could accomplish what you are trying to do using Observerable.forkJoin().

Comment: @Calidus any advice on how to fork.join()? Never really worked with that, thanks

Answer (score 6):

`forkJoin` combines the two subscriptions into a single one and returns an array of their results. It is extremely useful to use in `ngOnInit` when you need data from multiple sources before you can finish loading the component.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener(),
        this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()
    ).subscribe((data) => {
         // data[0] result from getWordUpdateListener
         this.thewords = data[0];
            this.thewords.map(word => {
              this.theHardWords.push(word.word);
              this.wordWithAnnotation.push(word);
            });
            this.wordsLoaded = true;

         // data[1] result from getPostUpdateListener
         this.posts.map(post => {
              if (post.id === this.id) {
                this.postIWant = post.fileText;
              }
            });
            this.postLoaded = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);
    }, (err) => {
        // error handling
    });
```

edit:added Import Statement for Observable in RXJS 5 and below

Edit: RXJS 6 update, changes import statment

```
import { forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
forkJoin(this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener(),
            this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()
).subscribe((data) => { \\do stuff}, (err) => { \\ do error stuff}
```

Edit 2: RXJS changed the signature of forkJoin it now takes an array

```
    forkJoin([this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener(),
            this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()]
).subscribe((data) => { \\do stuff}, (err) => { \\ do error stuff}
```

Comment: Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. I have imported both Observable and forkJoin.

Comment: Your are going to in to import it from rxjs, I updated my post.

Comment: It does not seem to get past the subscribe part, no errors just not getting through, any advice?

Comment: Are you not getting data back from the forkJoin? Or are you have trouble processing the data.

Comment: I have set `console.logs` all under the subscribe but none of them seem to be called. This is how it looks: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/81b65c4b4c3b19ec6545cb981dfbd698. But I seem to not be getting any result from this. Also checked the network and the requests are successful. @Calidus

Comment: Logging or inspecting the values in data. That will tell you if the problem is with the forkJoin or with the way you are processing the data.

Comment: Sorted it all now, but now I'm getting a problem with `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` Not sure why this is complaining now, so annoying. @Calidus

Comment: I don't see innerHTML in your code, sounds like isn't returning the value you expected.

Comment: Would I be able to show you the HTML or you are not interested? Thanks @Caldius

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176413/discussion-between-calidus-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1):

Because you need data from two separate streams at once you need to combine the streams in some way. Below is an example of how you could:

```
this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener().pipe(
  switchMap(thewords => {
    return this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener().pipe(
      map(posts => ({ thewords, posts }))
    );
  }),
)
.subscribe(({ thewords, posts }) => {
  this.complexWordIdentification(posts, thewords);
});
```

Comment: Struggling to implement this, il get back to this if I can sort it out, thanks.

Comment: Still seems to call it before the `this.postIWant` and `this.theHardWords` have loaded.

Comment: Remove the functionality that calculates those variables and put it all in the subscribe of the above

Comment: The idea here is you don't calculate this data in two different places but combine the two observables and calculate it in one place

Comment: I'm I going about it the right way? below is what I have changed 
      `.subscribe(({ thewords, posts }) => {
        this.posts.map(post => {
        if (post.id === this.id) {
            this.postIWant = post.fileText;
          }
        },
        this.thewords.map(word => {
          this.theHardWords.push(word.word);
          this.wordWithAnnotation.push(word);
        }));
        this.complexWordIdentification(posts, thewords);
      });`

Answer (score 1):

If you need both this.postIWant, this.theHardWords always on component initialization you can probably use angular resolve i.e. https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Example:-

```
class Backend {
  fetchTeam(id: string) {
    return 'someTeam';
  }
}

@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```